# sql query replace all specific values with a different value

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to replace specific values in one column with a new value but it does not work (no errors, no replacement of values, nothing happen).

```
UPDATE Components
SET Unit='kg'
WHERE Unit='КГ'
```

How can I replace all values "КГ" with "kg" in column Unit?

Comment: do you get any error, or the SQL statement is executed successfully?

Comment: be more clear. We don't even know if your problem is an error of if you simply don't know how to do. If this is the case, please even show some effort. Otherwise show us the error you are facing

Comment: Define *does not work* - do you get an error? If so: *what* error?? Does it not actually update the table? Or is something else happening?? *WHAT* is happening??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing that your `Unit` column is `NVarChar()` data type. Try following query:

```
UPDATE Components
SET Unit=N'kg'
WHERE Unit=N'КГ'
```

Another reason: If you have instead of update trigger on Components table and not update this column on it, your update not affected and no raise error too.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [Quotename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176114.aspx) to resolve this, it is used for this type of string.

```
UPDATE Components
SET Unit=QUOTENAME('kg')
WHERE Unit=QUOTENAME('КГ')
```

It is simple and direct query which you run, then its ok. Other wise as @Mehdi said, I also fever that statement.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/7515/quotename-function-in-sql-server.aspx